# How to encode bank account numbers before k-means?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have this large dataset (~400 000 rows) of transactions. Each transaction has the `source` and `destination` account number. Each of the two contains approximately 50 000 unique entries.

How do I encode these categorical variables? Obviously, one-hot encoding is not a choice, since this would take ~400GB of RAM to even store the encoded dataset. Is there a better way that uses way less RAM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factorize` and `Categorical` dtype to transform account to numerical id and keep the same id for each account across columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': {0: 'Acc1', 1: 'Acc1', 2: 'Acc3', 3: 'Acc2'},
                   'destination': {0: 'Acc2', 1: 'Acc3', 2: 'Acc2', 3: 'Acc4'}})

vals = pd.unique(df[['source', 'destination']].values.ravel('K'))

df[['src_id', 'dest_id']] = df[['source', 'destination']] \
                                .apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, vals).codes)
```

```
>>> df

  source destination  src_id  dest_id
0   Acc1        Acc2       0        2
1   Acc1        Acc3       0        1
2   Acc3        Acc2       1        2
3   Acc2        Acc4       2        3
```

Comment: But `src_id` and `dest_id` are categorical, not ordinal! Even though the account number `6` is no better than number `5` the k-means algorithm would assume it is. There is also a column `salaries`.

Comment: I'm agree. Maybe you can read this paper to help you: https://zenodo.org/record/1130687

Comment: I mean.. would factorize and Categorical make sense if used with the k-means algorithm? If so, I will accept it.

Comment: I have discovered this `KModes`  algorithm, maybe that will do. It's apparently KMeans for categorical factors. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/kmodes-clustering-algorithm-for-categorical-data/